# NameError: name 'base' is not defined OpenAI Gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

[Note that I am using `xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" jupyter notebook`]

I try to run a basic set of commands in OpenAI Gym

```
import gym
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
obs = env.reset()
env.render()
```

but I get the following error:

```
...

~/Downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py in <module>()
    225     else:
    226         from .carbon import CarbonConfig as Config
--> 227 del base
    228 
    229 # XXX remove

NameError: name 'base' is not defined
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

Solving your issue required getting the right combination of system dependencies and python dependencies. Paste this code into a cell in Colab and run it to install all of the dependencies (taking note of the specific version numbers used).

```
%%bash

# install required system dependencies
apt-get install -y xvfb x11-utils

# install required python dependencies (might need to install additional gym extras depending)
pip install gym[box2d]==0.17.* pyvirtualdisplay==0.2.* PyOpenGL==3.1.* PyOpenGL-accelerate==3.1.*
```

The final step is to run the following block of code to properly initialize the virtual display. The code in the below creates a virtual display in the background that your Gym Envs can connect to for rendering. You can adjust the size of the virtual buffer as you like but you must set `visible=False` when working with Xvfb.

This code only needs to be run once per session to start the display.

```
import pyvirtualdisplay


_display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=False,  # use False with Xvfb
                                    size=(1400, 900))
_ = _display.start()
```

For additional details check out the following [blog post](https://davidrpugh.github.io/stochastic-expatriate-descent/openai/binder/google-colab/2020/04/16/remote-rendering-gym-envs.html).

Comment: I got `Successfully installed EasyProcess-0.3 PyOpenGL-accelerate-3.1.5 box2d-py-2.3.8 pyvirtualdisplay-0.2.5` after running your commands. However still getting `NameError: name 'base' is not defined`

Comment: you miss the last part from the blog post. These commands also needs to be executed in Colab:
`import pyvirtualdisplay<cr>
  _display = pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=False, size=(1400, 900))<cr>
_ = _display.start()<cr>`

Comment: I had to run `apt-get install swig` before running the pip install.
But otherwise this solved it for me

Comment: I continue to get the error in spite of pasting both these cells. See https://imgur.com/UvnOqFI for the screenshot and error logs.

Comment: Btw you will have to restart notebook. to make it work too

Answer (score 6):

It's work for me. (And I just met the same problem)

```sh
git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git
cd gym
pip install -e .
```

You can also have a try,

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pyglet
# pyglet==1.2.4?
```

Before that, I installed gym with pip, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @Mikev emmm, maybe problem occurs in: `pip install gym`

Answer (score 2):

change the code as follow

```
import gym
print(gym.__version__)# for me: 0.15.4
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
obs = env.reset()
for i in range(1000):# it's changable
    env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    env.render()# won't work in Google Colab
env.close()
```

Comment: maybe it's from your system, check your gym version. note that render function won't work on colab and you need IPython notebook tricks to display it - or save a video from rendering

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

Uninstall the packages with these commands:

```
pip uninstall pyglet
pip uninstall gym
```

Then install the packages using these commands:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyglet
conda install -c conda-forge gym
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try update glfw to glfw 3.3+

Comment: Why? What does that do?

Answer (score -1):

You could run the algorithm from the command line:

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --exp_name CartPole --env CartPole-v0
```

Here, ppo is the proximal policy optimization algorithm, but you can run any of the algorithms you want.