# NameError: name 'base' is not defined, while running open AI gym in GOOGLE COLAB

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pytorch, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning

I am going through the tutorial DQN reinforcement learning in Pytorch.org,https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/reinforcement_q_learning.html

But here when I am trying to render a screen and display using python display, I am getting name base not found. Can anyone help me here? If you want to clear any clarity about the question, I am here
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472940/nameerror-name-base-is-not-defined-openai-gym

Answer (score 3):

Use the gpu on colab. If with that isn't enought execute this cell at the beginning

```
!apt install xvfb -y
!pip install pyvirtualdisplay
!pip install piglet

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
display.start()
```

Comment: Got another error when `GLException: No GL context; create a Window first
`

Comment: Solved, by using `nvidia-xconfig`